# How to implement data container with instance["variable_name"] access?

Tags: .net, datareader

I am using `DataTable["content_name"]`, `DataReader["content_name"]`, but I do not know, how to create my own object using this way to access data.

I want to create datareader result container (DataTable makes me some unwanted queries to db on firebird).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
public class MyClass
{
  private List<String> _myData;

  public MyClass()
  {
    _myData = new List<String>();
  }

  public String this[String argIndex]
  {
    get
    {
      return _myData[argIndex];
    }
    set
    {
      _myData[argIndex] = value;
    }
  }
}
```

It's the this bit that usually stumps you until you know it, bit unobvious...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an Indexer, Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add to your class a dictionary and a new indexer property:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> dataTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public string this[string key]
{
   get
   {
      if (this.dataTable.ContainsKey(key))
          return this.dataTable[key];
      else
          return string.Empty;
   }
   set
   {
       if (this.dataTable.ContainsKey(key))
          this.dataTable[key] = value;
   }
}
```

Of course, you can add some Exceptions throwing or filling your private `dataTable` field somewhere else in your code

Comment: Your code won't compile. You should have `this` instead of `DataTable`.

Comment: Oh.. sugar. Thanks. just mistype